# cypher: query for a pattern and parts of a pattern

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am searching a collection for small subgraphs using cypher.  I'm looking for the pattern A->B->C but I want to also see instances where A, B, or C are isolated and subsets of the pattern such as instances where the pattern is incomplete eg. A->B or B->C

I know I can get isolated nodes using the following for each node type

```
MATCH (a:A)
WHERE NOT EXISTS ((a)--())
RETURN a
```

and I can match my pattern with

```
MATCH (a:A)-[r1]->(b:B)-[r2]->(c:C)
RETURN a,b,c,r1,r2
```

How can I search for parts of the pattern where there is say, A->B but no follow on relation for B?  Finding incomplete patterns is required.

Note: the database is in Neo4j and it is not a fully connected graph but rather a set of many independent small graphs, hence why I can find 'part' of a pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only three nodes, then below will give you all subsets of the pattern (A)-(B)-(C). That is, isolated node A, B, C, connected A-B, B-C and A-C.

```
MATCH (p) WHERE NOT EXISTS ((p)--()) and labels(p) in [['A'], ['B'], ['C']]
RETURN p
UNION ALL
MATCH p=(:A)--(b:B) WHERE NOT EXISTS ((b)--(:C))
RETURN p
UNION ALL
MATCH p=(b:B)--(:C) WHERE NOT EXISTS ((:A)--(b))
RETURN p
UNION ALL
MATCH p=(:A)--(:C) 
RETURN p
```

Sample Data:

[image]

```
CREATE (a1:A {title: "a1"})
CREATE (a2:A {title: "a2"})
CREATE (a3:A {title: "a3"})
CREATE (b1:B {title: "b1"})
CREATE (b2:B {title: "b2"})
CREATE (b3:B {title: "b3"})
CREATE (c1:C {title: "c1"})
CREATE (c2:C {title: "c2"})
CREATE (c3:C {title: "c3"})
CREATE (a1)-[:LINKS]->(b1)
CREATE (b2)-[:LINKS]->(c2) 
CREATE (a3)-[:LINKS]->(b3)-[:LINKS]->(c3);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: if I add to the end of your query ```if I add to the end of your query `UNION ALL
MATCH p=(:A)--(:B)--(:C)
RETURN p` then on the toy data set I also get the a3-b3-c3 pattern.  But when I try this on a real world data set I only get the three node pattern but not the isolated or partial patterns from the first part of the query.  I can run the query to get the partial patterns OR run it to get the complete pattern but not both in the same query.  It's like adding a final `UNION ALL` overwrites the preceding returns.

Comment: ignore my last comment.  The limitation was the number of nodes the screen could show b/c I'm using community version of Neo4J Bloom.  Just putting this note in case someone else forgets to consider that.

Answer (score 1):

The below query should work, for the the above schema, you described, you can modify it according to your needs:

```
MATCH p = (x)-->() WHERE (NOT (x)-->()-->() AND NOT ()-->(x)-->()) AND labels(x) IN [['A'], ['B']]
RETURN p
UNION ALL
MATCH (p) WHERE NOT (p)--()
RETURN p
```

Comment: This could be good to use as a template for something to automatically generate queries something I'm hoping for later.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using replace. I encountered a simpler problem in genealogy: x-linked inheritance. It is characterized by lack of father to son inheritance. You can find paths by concatenating the sex and then filtering out 'MM', as follows:

```
match p=(n:Person{RN:1})-[:father|mother*0..99]->(x)
with n,x,reduce(s='', g in nodes(p) |s + g.sex) as cs
with n,x, cs where cs=replace(cs,'MM','')
return x.RN, cs
```

One example of the concatenated output:

```
MFFFFMFF
```

Perhaps you can use this to accept or exclude patterns of A, B, and C?

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but I learned something from this.  tnx!